# NAT mode virtual machines shows same IP address

Tags: networking, ip, virtualbox, ip-address

I have two virtual machine running on a virtual box.

VM 1 and 
VM 2

The network is in the NAT mode (default).

Both the machines have the same IP address.So I assume that they are in two different networks.

My requirement is that I should be able to communicate from 
VM 1 to VM 2 using IP.
i.e  I would like to ping from VM 1 to VM 2 and back.

For this I would prefer if they were a part of the same network.Is there some routing functionality implemented in Virtual Box?

How do I created and internal network with two VM's that can talk to each other using IP.

Comment: why the negative score?

Comment: virtualbox, and in particular this networking implementation with it, is hardly suitable for production, despite its vendor's vehement insistence to the contrary.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure VirtualBox for the VM to have different addresses but that would have no effect on the fact they cannot ping each other.

NAT is designed to allow outgoing traffic from the VM, not incoming one.

Just use any other networking mode.

Comment: In other networking mode's I can't seem to get the connection for some reason.

Comment: I am guessing there is no DHCP server running on my home network to assign ip addresses in a bridged network.

Comment: If you are using VirtualBox at home, you are in the wrong site. serverfault is for professional admins.